# Pass value one by one to the query condition and combine multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-like

I want to get all the role_ids based on the permission id from the #permission table with the matching permissionId in the #source_audit table Value column.

And then combine all the role_id for a given permission_id in a single row.

Any help is much appreciated

```
create table #permission (
    [permission_id] char(6) not null
)
   
insert into #permission
    values
    ('-336'),
    ('-12016'),
    ('-12014')
    
create table #source_audit
(
    role_id int, 
    value nvarchar(max)
)
    
insert into #source_audit
    values 
    ( 2453, '{"PermissionId":-336, "ConstraintTypeId":7}'),
    ( 2003, '{"PermissionId":-336, "ConstraintTypeId":7}'),
    ( 2123, '{"PermissionId":-12016, "ConstraintTypeId":7}'),
    ( 2893, '{"PermissionId":-14567, "ConstraintTypeId":7}')
```

Query tried so far and not working

```
    select srae.*, x.Permission_Id
    from #source_audit as srae
    inner join #permission as x
        on srae.value like '%' + CONVERT(varchar(32), permission_id) + '%' 
        and srae.value like '%"ConstraintTypeId":7%'
```

Result Table

| permission_id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| -336 | 2453, 2003 |
| -12016 | 2123 |

Comment: What do you mean by " join with another table with the like condition or any other possible way"? It may help to post sample data. Please don't write "not working". Explain inputs, and expected output and why it's not what you expected (or an error message)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you MUST and you understand the consequences, at least use the current (not deprecated) syntax.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the feedback. I updated my question to be clear now. Appreciate your help

Comment: @SMor Thanks and modified by question to be clear. please take a look

Comment: OK your `#source_audit` table contains *almost* valid JSON, you should correct it. And how does `-12016` match `12016`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#source_audit.value` data is JSON, so we can use `OPENJSON` on it to pull out the values.

It appears you want to match on absolute values of `permission_id` (ignoring negative sign).

```
SELECT
  p.permission_id,
  roles = STRING_AGG(s.role_id, ', ')
FROM permission p
JOIN source_audit s
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.value)
        WITH ( PermissionId int, ConstraintTypeId int ) j
  ON ABS(j.PermissionId) = ABS(p.permission_id) AND j.ConstraintTypeId = 7
GROUP BY
  p.permission_id;
```

On SQL Server 2016 or earlier, you need to use the `FOR XML` method

```sql
SELECT
  p.permission_id,
  roles = STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(', ', s.role_id)
      FROM source_audit s
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.value)
        WITH ( PermissionId int, ConstraintTypeId int ) j
      WHERE ABS(j.PermissionId) = ABS(p.permission_id)
        AND j.ConstraintTypeId = 7
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(', '), '')
FROM permission p;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7cebe/6)

Comment: my bad, it's a JSON, i missed parenthesis while posting the question, and also permission_id is exact values in both the tables. I updated my question. my version is not supporting the STRING_AGG function 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Charlieface, can you modify the query for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry to bother you, with the valid JSON in the #source_audit table and with the latest query, I am getting an error now.  JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'P' is found at position 4. i am not familiar with the query JSON in sql and am trying to understand this query as well.

Comment: got it . have to modify the OPENJSON at the other place as well. thanks so much for your help .

Comment: Umm forgot to remove the addition of `{}` from the second version, fixed now. You may want to check by pasting your JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ Also realized I made it unnecessarily complicated by using` OPENJSON` twice, it's not necessary